# Selecting a sibling with constraints

Tags: xpath

I've got an XML file in the vein of

```
<chapter template="A" id='1'/>
<chapter template="B"/>
<chapter template="B"/>
<chapter template="A" id='2'/>
<chapter template="B"/>
<chapter template="B"/>
<chapter template="B"/>
<chapter template="B"/>
<chapter template="C"/>
```

And I've got an XSLFO to process these chapters. The last chapter that has template "A" needs some special processing. The id attribute isn't something I can filter for (just added it here for illustration). 
I've got a `template match="chapter"` that does the general processing for all chapters. Somewhere inside that code block is a section that only applies to the last chapter that uses template A. To execute this code block for that chapter only, I've got this test:

```
if test="following-sibling::chapter[not(@template = 'B')]/@template = 'C'"
```

So I'm trying to find the first following sibling that isn't template B, and checking if this sibling has template C. (it's been set up so that template C is always the last chapter). 
The XPath above returns 'true' when processing chapter id=1 and id=2, so it's too broad. It's true when the chapter has any following sibling with template C.
So I'm thinking: I'll constrain the test to look only at the first following sibling that isn't template B:

```
if test="following-sibling::chapter[not(@template = 'B')][1]/@template = 'C'"
```

But this returns false for all chapters. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hmm, your second query looks correct and returns the expected result (false for id=1, true for id=2) within BaseX.

Comment: It fails for me in Oxygen using the full XML file. Thanks for confirming that the query should work.

Comment: Last chapter with template A you say? Why not test for no following siblings with template A: self::chapter[@template='A'] and count(following-sibling::chapter[@template='A'])=0

Comment: I got the solution provided by @pault. to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like `//chapter[@template='A'][last()]`?

Comment: That returns the attributes of the last chapter with template A, it seems.

Comment: Is that not what you wanted? If not, could you clarify the question please.

Comment: I've clarified the question. I was looking for an XPath statement that has a boolean result. I suppose I could use your statement and compare it to the current chapter, but I haven't quite figured that out yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I completely failed to grasp what you are looking for.